# Why does Anglican refer to the religious sect rather than any other aspects of “Englishness”?

Tags: meaning, etymology

It seems intuitively to mean “roughly English in style or form” in the sense of how Georgian or Edwardian means “evocative of the style prevalent in the era of [those respective monarchs]”.

Why does it seem in practice to specifically refer to the religious sect rather than a more general idea like architectural style or a type of cuisine?

Comment: Isn't this just one example of the very general phenomenon of 'getting that meaning first, etymology be damned'? *Homophobia* means *prejudice against gay people* rather than fear of things being the same; a *board meeting* is a meeting of a certain group of people, not a meeting of a plank; *lesbian* means *attracted to other women* rather than *from Lesbos*.

Comment: That’s another good perspective, albeit in this case Geoff’s happens to shine further.

Comment: See also "catholic" which means roughly "universal" but is used specifically to refer to certain Christian groups.

Comment: I also find it interesting that the verb form, *anglicize*, is back to referring to general Englishness rather than having a religious connotation.

Comment: @dbmag9 As I understand it, Lesbian *also* means "from Lesbos", and the inhabitants of Lesbos aren't too happy with its dual meaning.

Comment: Point: words typically have more than one meaning.  Even though one usage/meaning of a word may be more common, that in no way invalidates other meanings/usages.

Comment: It is not a religious sect. It is called a Protestant denomination.

Comment: @dbmag9 Fyi, a board meeting is called that because very early ones were held around a table made of a board.

Comment: @Lambie [sect](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sect): "1. a body of persons adhering to a particular religious faith; a religious denomination." [sect](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sect): "1. An offshoot of a larger religion or denomination. " [sect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sect): "1b a religious denomination"  [sect](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/sect_n1): "I.1.a. A branch or subdivision of a larger religious group, typically distinguished by differences in doctrine and observance; esp. a recognized autonomous branch of a religion; a religious denomination."

Comment: @R,M. Usage dictates Protestant denomination, not sect. There really is no argument here...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a word similar to Georgian or Edwardian to mean, *of England*, derived from Angles (the Latin for the the people of England, or more precisely the Germanic Anglii people who migrated to England in the post-Roman era), and that is **Anglian**.

"Anglican" specifically derives from the Latin, *Anglicana ecclesia*, literally, The Church of England.

Comment: Does Anglian still find current use?

Comment: Actually according to Google Anglian seems to rather mean of the Angles than of England.

Comment: It is certainly dated, and it mostly survives in references to East Anglia, where local businesses and organisations use it. However, Angle is still used to refer to the English (and more broadly, the British) but primarily in the form Anglo, such as in _Anglo-French_ which still appears frequently in the printed news media.

Comment: There is a better word derived from “Angle” to refer to the people you mention, and it is of course “English”.

Comment: Wouldn’t that be Angular?

Comment: @user3840170 So, if the English were continuing some practice just because they've "always done it that way," would that be Angular momentum?

Comment: @reirab Actually that would be inertia. The London Marathon is, however, Angular momentum.

Comment: "Angl-" (versus "Engl-") also survives in other languages' names for English (e.g., French *anglaise*, Czech *anglický*, Greek *αγγλική*).  I don't know why *we* don't call our language "Anglish", but etymology rarely takes the most straightforward path.

Comment: @Dan There was a vowel shift sometime, which is how the country became England.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins:  And if the continued existence of the London Marathon were ever threatened, there might be a society formed for the conservation of Angular momentum.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert though the conservation of Angular momentum is often revolutionary, i.e. going round in circles, like modern politics

Answer (score 9):

The term was used in the Magna Carta to refer  to the English Church and the sense has retained its specificity ever since:

According to the site Oxford Languages:

Anglican:

> early 17th century: from medieval Latin Anglicanus (its adoption suggested by Anglicana ecclesia ‘the English church’ in the Magna Carta), from Latin Anglicus, from Angli.

> The word Anglican originates in *Anglicana ecclesia libera sit*, a phrase from Magna Carta dated 15 June 1215, meaning '*the Anglican Church shall be free'*.

(Wikipedia)

Answer (score 6):

It is perhaps worth noting that the word "English" itself can be used in more or less the sense you describe it, according to the [OED (adjective sense 4)](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/english_adj?tab=meaning_and_use#5416271):

> 4. Characteristic of or marked by the behaviour of an English person; possessed of virtues or failings regarded as peculiar to English people.

Adjective sense 1 could also match for non-human objects:

> 1. Of or belonging to England (or Britain) or its inhabitants.

Comment: How is that second definition one of a noun?

Comment: @Seekinganswers - None of the uses we've covered are nouns ; they're adjectival qualifiers of the nouns "people" and "church" subjected to nominalisation and/or zero derivation. The sentences have been contracted in conventional uses to remove the actual noun from the phrase leaving the qualifier, which could itself appear to be a noun - or even a proper noun. If one instance of this is more common, it will take precedence, which is why people think of Ignacio Anaya's tortillas and not his bicycle.

Comment: IMHO this is the correct answer to "why do we use Anglican mostly just to refer to the church of that name?"  Because in most peoples' minds there's a more transparent word that has the same meaning" "English".  Except that, or course" the "English Church" would be wrong in most peoples minds because "Anglican" is how the church is traditionally/commonly referred to.

Comment: @Seekinganswers You're right, I meant "adjective" in both cases. Edited the post to fix

Comment: Right so as in “English food,” “English music/art/literature” etc

Comment: @RBarryYoung Also, [Westminster Cathedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westminster_Cathedral) is an English church, but it is not an Anglican church.

Answer (score 1):

Because we already have the word "English" to refer to other general aspects of "Englishness".